# Convert input String into JsonArray in Android

Tags: java, arrays, json, string, android-studio

I want to convert the input Coordinates into JsonArray.
I'm new to  android can any one help me how to convert the input double coordinates into json array
I have taken double values as the input coordinates and tried converting it into string n have put it into jsonObjects but i want to put it in JsonArray so that multiple inputs coordinates will have multiple objects.
here is my code.
I want to convert the String in JsonArray

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button submit;
    TextView test;
    EditText longi;
    EditText lati;
    JSONArray array =null;
    JSONObject object = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        longi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.longi);
        lati = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lati);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Submit);
        double longdata = 21.483638;
        double latidata = 24.6425675;
        final String json = "{\"longitude\":" + "\"" + String.valueOf(longdata) + "\"" + "," + "\"latitude\":" + "\"" + String.valueOf(latidata) + "\"" + "}";
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JsonObject(json);
                    Log.d("My App",obj.toString());
                    }
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                     Log.d("My App","Could not parse malformed JSON:"+json+" ");
                }
            }
        });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared longitude and latitude as constants. How will you get multiple long and lat values?

If I'm assuming it correct you want to convert longitude and latitude to an array so
first, you would need to declare 2 arrays here is an example

```
 List<Double> longitudeList = new ArrayList<>();
    longitudeList.add(21.483638);
    List<Double> latitudeList = new ArrayList<>();
    latitudeList.add(24.6425675);

    final String json =
        "{\"longitude\":["
            + longitudeList.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","))
            + "],\"latitude\":["
            + latitudeList.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","))
            + "]}";
```

If you do this way your json looks like this

```
{"longitude":[21.483638],"latitude":[24.6425675]}
```

Then pass this to JSONobject constructor and apply your logics.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help,but i want to put the jsonbjects in one JsonArray can you help in that? So when ever the input coordinates will change it will be added in the json objects so i can put that in the server